# Replacing data in a .csv file

Tags: python, strings, python-2.x, csv

The code works well and does what I intend for it to do. In essence, it opens a file referenced as 'resource'. This is a .csv file. I then searches for the keys in the dictionary and for each key that it encounters, it replaces it with the value - the dictionary being 'rep'. It then exports this to a new .csv file.

The above just seems slightly cumbersome and so I just wonder if there is a slicker / more pythonistic way of achieving the above? I think the non-slick part of my code is the writing of the amended data to a new file but I seek any feedback regarding improving my code.

```
with open(resource,'rb') as f:
   data = f.read()
   rep = {"Incoming Call" : "Voice (in)",
          "Outgoing Call" : "Voice (out)",
          "Incoming SMS" : "SMS (in)",
          "Outgoing SMS" : "SMS (out)"}
   for i, j in rep.iteritems():
      print i, j
      data = data.replace(i, j)
   with open("output.txt", "w") as outputfile:
      outputfile.write(data)
      outputfile.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

The process you're using is better than trying to read and write the same file, which is just asking for a headache. However there is another way, which will particularly help if you need to use this on a larger file. You can read the file line by line, writing the replaced lines to your output file. This is less memory intensive as only a line is read at a time.

```
with open(resource,'rb') as f, open("output.txt", "w") as outputfile:
    for line in f:
        for i, j in rep.iteritems():
            line = line.replace(i, j)
        outputfile.write(line)
```

Note: I'd move the `rep` declaration out before you open either file, and I removed the superfluous `print` call now that it's running over every line.

Additionally, I don't think you need a dictionary for your mapping. It seems to semantically make sense, but offers no actual advantage to you. Just a tuple of tuple pairs would work fine, and I'd rename it too:

```
replacements = (
                ("Incoming Call", "Voice (in)"),
                ("Outgoing Call", "Voice (out)"),
                ("Incoming SMS", "SMS (in)"),
                ("Outgoing SMS", "SMS (out)"),
               )
```

Also a minor improvement for your loop, you can use the unpacking operator to simplify things a little:

```
for pair in replacements:
    line = line.replace(*pair)
```

`*` is the unpacking operator, it unpacks a 2-item tuple into 2 arguments for you. I prefer this as I find it more readable and makes for a better name (`pair` rather than `i, j`).

Answer (score 1):

You do weird things with your context managers. Namely `outputfile.close()` is completely unnecessary as it is already handled by the `with` statement.

Also you do not need to keep the input file opened until the end of the process. You can close it right after you get the data (`data = f.read()`) by de-indenting by one level everything that comes after.